# <video> tag not working android emulator

Tags: android, html5-video

I am new android development. I am using the video tag. But while running it on the emulator the video does not play. Although the video works fine on browser. Can some one help me out in what I am missing.

```
 <video id="video" autoplay width="500" height="400" controls="controls">
<source src="http://ec2-50-16-201-31.compute-1.amazonaws.com/p/100/sp/10000/flvclipper/entry_id/0_hu1hm4qg" />
not working
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var video = document.getElementById('video');
video.addEventListener('click',function(){
    video.play();
},false);
```

I am using phonegap as well.
Java Code : App.java

```
public class App extends DroidGap {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

    appView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                String contentDisposition, String mimeType, long size) {
            Intent viewIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            viewIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url), mimeType);
            try {
                startActivity(viewIntent);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                Log.w("YourLogTag",
                        "Couldn't find activity to view mimetype: "
                                + mimeType);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Has anyone faced a similar issue. I have searched quite a bit online, but not able to narrow down the issue.
I am using android 3.2 and phonegap 1.0.0

Comment: How are you trying to display it? In a WebView inside of one of your own applications? Or in the stock browser installed on the emulator? Have you tried on a real device?

Comment: @Tim: I am trying to display in WebView inside my own application. I am currently using emulator, have not tried it on a device as yet.

Comment: Post the java code you are using to show the video. Have you called .setJavascriptEnabled(true);? If your on honeycomb I would enable hardwareAccerlation in your manifest as well to be safe. I know some content in WebViews does not behave on honeycomb without this flag set.

Comment: I have not called the .setJavascriptEnabled(true). Where do I have to use this file and how do I call it. I have enabled hardwareAccerlation also.

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with phoneGap but you need to call it on your WebView. loadUrl(String url) is a method of the WebView class so assuming the DroidGap class extends WebView then you'd call `super.setJavascriptEnabled(true);` If DroidGap isn't actually extending WebView and is instead just passing along what you give it in loadUrl to a private WebView object contained inside it, then using super is not going to work. You'll have to find a way to get a reference to the WebView that is actually being used to display your page. Maybe droidGap has something like .getWebView() or something?